# how to call function from other fragment class

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, overflow

I'm trying to call this function  `public void  arrowClick()`

is inside my main fragment `public class CounterMain extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{`

the fragment is extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

I want to call this function from another Custmoe Dialog fragment

```
public class CustmoeDialog extends DialogFragment {
```

I tried    `((CounterMain)getActivity()).arrowClick();`

but I can't use it it says  `android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be cast to my.example.CounterMain`

and the

```
CounterMain x = new CounterMain(); x.arrowClick();
```

it makes my app to stop working when I call it

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call activity method by this way

```
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```

and from activity you can directly call by this way

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();//if added by xml
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment_id);
fragment.yourPublicMethod();
```

if you added fragment via code and used a tag string when you added your fragment, use findFragmentByTag instead:

```
YourFragmentClass fragment = (YourFragmentClass)fm.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not cast from ACTIVITY to FRAGMENT
But to cast from GLOBAL ACTIVITY to your ACTIVITY

Or create INTERFACE and implement it in ACTIVITY

Then cast it in FRAGMENT from ACTIVITY to INTERFACE

And on the question:

See here the right way how to implement

[Basic communication between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13701071/3439902)