# change the text color inside a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, text, colors, fragment

I have just started working with fragments in android. In my main layout, I have two buttons. When I click one button it displays the fragment (which is a piece of text). Now what I want is that when I click the other button, it should change the color of that text inside the fragment. Is that possible ? If yes, then kindly give me an example code. Because I could not find it on internet.

Thank you.

Comment: take a look -  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: this also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @shine_joseph. I will look at them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
b.putExtra("Color" , "Red");
Fragment_2 f2 = new Fragment_2();
f2.setArguments(b);
```

and in your fragment, onCreateView() you can get it as:

```
String color = getArguments().getString("Color");
```

Now, set that color in your textView or related views.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes; one which is your main layout or activity that displays fragment on click of button and another class which is your fragment then make a method in your fragment class

```
public void changeColor(){textView.setColor(xxx);}
```

And call that method from your other class at button click like this

```
new YourFragmentClass().changeColor();
```

Comment: This looks quite straight forward. I would like to use this method. But I cant  use this "FindViewbyID" in fragment class. How do i declare TextView there?