# What is the most effective way to get edittext data on different fragments in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a survey app. I am using tabs for different survey titles. Now I am trying to get all of edittexts or check box data at last tab in save button onclick method. What is the most effective way to get all of text fields data at last tab(last fragment) ? Thanks for help.

Comment: do you want  to save data or just need data to the nxt fragment

Comment: I will post the data to a web service at last fragment (actually when survey completed)

Comment: Implement `interface`. Call method from fragment and implement in activity

Comment: If all the `Fragment`s are attached to the same `Activity`, then use an `interface`

Comment: how can I use interface can you give me a reference for use it ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232179/sharing-data-between-two-fragments-of-of-one-activity/33232538#33232538) shows how `Fragment`s can communicate with each other via their `Activity` with an `interface`