# How to use OnActivtyforResult to get values from Fragment B to Fragment A

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult

In my application i have two fragments i.e fragment A and fragment B,where Fragment A with EditText with a button and on fragment B contains list of items.
Here is my question,When i use to click on button on Fragment A it should move to Fragment B and on clicking on list items on fragment B should send back clicked item to Fragment A and should show in EditText in Fragment A .
Thanks

Comment: [Basic Communication between fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create interface via listnerer and send object with help constructor to other fragment. Main fragment must be implemented by your new interface.