# Execute fragment method from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

I will try to explain the cenario.

Look this image 1:

[image: cenario]

I have one Fragment called HOME with a toolbar.

In that Fragment i have a ViewPager with 2 fragments:

Fragment A and Fragment B

When the fragment A is activy, the toolbar has a action button that call another activity.

In that "another activity" i have a ViewPager with 2 fragments:
Fragment C and Fragment D.

What i need is, when i click on a button inside Fragment C, the "another activity" closes and execute a callback inside Fragment A.

I tried with startActivityforresult but without sucess.

Tried too wiht a public interface inside fragment C that is implemented by fragment A, but i think this does not work like intended.

Anyone can give me a tip?

And sorry my english, not my native language.

Some code to explain:

Inside Fragment A

When the button inside toolbar is clicked him call "Another activity"

```
startActivityForResult(IAddPedido, RESULT_ADD);
```

The "another activity" create the viewpager and setup 2 fragments:

```
fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

adapterPedidosAdd = new AdapterPedidosAdd(fragManager);

// Seto adaptador passando o Id
viewPagerPedAdd.setAdapter(adapterPedidosAdd);

tLayoutPedAdd.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

    tLayoutPedAdd.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerPedAdd);

    }

});
```

Inside fragment C, when i click on "button" him will call set the result and call "finish()".

```
// Get the "another activity" and set the result
getActivity().setResult(1);

// Close the "another activity"        
getActivity().finish();
```

And then, inside Fragment A i have the "onActivityResult":

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

But the "onActivityResult" inside Fragment A is never called.

Maybe i have to create "onActivityResult" inside "Home" and then, get the instance of fragment A to call a methode inside him?

PS.: The "Home" is aready an fragment, because i have a NavigationDrawer.

Comment: check out [eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: You should be able to do this with startactivityforresult. How is it not working?

Comment: I would like to recommend another event bus library http://square.github.io/otto/ . You have an example here https://github.com/square/otto/tree/master/otto-sample/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/sample

Comment: Yes use a lib or.... you could just write up a simple method here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33756734/4440874).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getActivity.setResult()` is not work in your code because of life cycle of fragments and activity.

> this code shouldn't be in onDestroy(fragment). onDestroy happens after the activity is already finished, and onActivityResult was called.

instead of that

> this code needs to in the code that closes the activity/fragment, like on back key pressed, or a close button onClick

I tested your case scenario in my sample project and it's working

Comment: I have edited my answer, try to set Result in your another activity using an interface from fragment C/D

Comment: So, tried putting getActivity.setResult(1) inside onDestroy (inside Fragment C) but doesn't work.

The onActivityResult isn't called

Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Will, try using the interface

Comment: look the suggested part of answer (2nd yellow paragraph)

Comment: Lemme know if you could solve the problem, otherwise I will share the dropbox link with you. It's 1:35 AM in my side so it's time to sleep

Comment: Sorry. I haven't been able to solve.

Can you share your code with me, please?

Comment: Solved the problem with de EvenBus library. But, anyway, thank you for you attention and pacience.