# How to send data(int) from a fragment class to a view class

Tags: android

I have a fragment class `Frag2` and a view class `Rectangle` which sends onDraw to another fragment class `Frag1`, and i need to send some data to `Rectangle` from `Frag 2`.
what do i do ? :D

(sorry its abit messy ive been trying everything for last 24 hours.)

Frag 2

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

TextView changingText;
Button changeTextButton;

Button XButton;
Button YButton;

private int SecondX;

NumberPicker Pick100 = null;
private int entered;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_layout, container, false);


    changingText = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    changeTextButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button);


    XButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonX);
    YButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonY);

    Pick100 = (NumberPicker) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.secondD);



    changeTextViewValueRandomlyOnButtonClick();
    return myInflatedView;
}


private void changeTextViewValueRandomlyOnButtonClick() {
    final String[] text = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};


    changeTextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int random = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

            if (random == 100) changingText.setText(text[3]);
            if (random > 90 && random <= 99) changingText.setText(text[2]);
            if (random < 60 && random >= 1) changingText.setText(text[0]);
            if (random >= 60 && random <= 90) changingText.setText(text[1]);
        }

    });
}
```

You can ignore most of it really. Im trying to send Pick100 to this class

```
public class Rectangle extends View {
//FragmentTwo F2 = new FragmentTwo();


public Rectangle(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Rectangle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Rectangle(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d("X","RED DOT EUQALS TO "+x);


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(x,100,x+60,100+60,paint);
}
```

}

The Rectangle works fine.It sends a rect to Frag1 i just want to be able to send the number here and sub it in x ( int rectangle)

Frag 1 class :

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View myInflatedView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout,container,false);


    return myInflatedView;
}
```

}

Frag 1 xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/Frag1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000">


<com.redot.puzzle1.Rectangle
    android:id="@+id/Rect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: Explain in details, the relation between Rectangle-Frag2 & Frag1-Frag2 are not clear. For a single (int) value, you can pass it to Rectangle by constructor while instantiating Rectangle  in Frag 2 class.

Comment: oh sorry I thought there is a general solution for it ill post more details in a min

Comment: There are ways to send data from fragment to fragment (`fragment.setArguments(bundle);`) , activity to fragment ([using interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158820/4802664)), activity to activity (using intent extra).

Comment: I have tried bundle multiple times but for some reason it didnt work and i stopped trying. is it different when you send from frag to a view class?

Comment: You can just make a `setX(int x)` method in the Rectangle class. You get that Rectangle via `findViewById`

Comment: is Rectangle going to be part of the layout in fragment1?

Comment: @chaitanya yes there it's in the frag 1 layout

Comment: @cricket_007 ill try that right now 1 min

Comment: Add Frag1 class and Frag1 view xml in the question

Comment: @amirsoltani can't you get a reference to the Rectangle view when you inflate the fragment layout in onCreateView and pass the arguments? As mentioned by other commenters, you can pass arguments using the fragment.setArguments() or by defining an interface

Comment: @HassanTareq I've dont it

Comment: @chaitanya I've tried creating bundle and sending it as an arg but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly sure you can simply define a `void setX(int x)` in the Rectangle class.

In whatever Fragment you've put the Rectangle View, you would need something like

```
// Make a field for this
rect = (Rectangle) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.Rect);

// Call your method whenever
rect.setX(x);
```

Note: Looks like you are trying to randomly change the size of a view and expecting the `onDraw` method to do that change.

I think you should be using [a **`Canvas`** object](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) instead if you want to be working with Shapes and such

Comment: Ive posted the Frag 1 class and xml. the rectangle is in the xml so i cant call it from frag2 or i think i cant.

Comment: Okay, then you need some instance of Frag1 and use `setArguments()` on it

Comment: just to be clear I should send rectangle from fragment 1 to 2 then setX in fragmet 2 then use it in rectangle?

Comment: It sounds complicated, but yes. You can try a simple string to get started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments

Comment: Thank you very much, btw i'll be trying to learn https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html this instead

Answer (score 0):

Create a static field in Rectangle class `public static int pick100Value = 0` and subtract `pick100Value` from `x` in onDraw()

```
public class Rectangle extends View {
    public static int pick100Value = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // ...
        canvas.drawRect(x - pick100Value , 100, (x - pick100Value)  + 60, 100 + 60, paint);
    }
}
```

In FragmentTwo listen to the onValueChanged and set `Rectangle.pick100Value = newVal`

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements OnValueChangeListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two_layout, container, false);


        changingText = (TextView) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        changeTextButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button);


        XButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonX);
        YButton = (Button) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.buttonY);

        Pick100 = (NumberPicker) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.secondD);
        Pick100.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

        changeTextViewValueRandomlyOnButtonClick();
        return myInflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        Rectangle.pick100Value = newVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: In fragment 2 it i get an error it says it cant resolve `pick100Value `

Comment: Did you create static field ? `public static int pick100Value` in Rectangle.

Comment: I updated my answer: instead of anonymous implement OnValueChangeListener  in Frag2 and `Pick100.setOnValueChangedListener(this);`

Comment: it said the frag2 class must be abstract or implement onValueChange() but when i implemented it ran but its buggy the rectangle doesnt show up as well as fragment 2

Comment: I dot think the way im trying is a not the way to go so im gonna try a new way, it got too complicated anyways THank You so much

Comment: `Pick100 = (NumberPicker) myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.secondD);` Then how did you get Pick100 value before? if you were not listening to `OnValueChangeListener` in Frag2?

Comment: well i didnt get there first i was looking for a way to send the data

Comment: `OnValueChangeListener` is an interface and therefore implementing it in Frag2 should not hurt. Also, creating a static field in Rectangle class would not cause problem either

Comment: idk what the problem is I just copied your code. the rectangle and frag 2 layout dont show up im pretty sure there is a better way.I'll be looking for it tomorrow and if you want i can informe you when i've found it  thank you