# Add a button dynamically from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am building an android app and I am rather new to it. I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically add a button to a fragment by pressing a button on another fragment. For example, I have a fragment (A) that saves an input from a user and displays it in a listview on fragment (B) so I want to add a button into Fragment (B) for every user input.

[Fragment A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcu3S.png)

[Popup window when fab is clicked (B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAxfn.png)

Comment: What you need is [basic-communication-between-two-fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments).

Comment: plz post pictures of the scenerio

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how it is implemented in the app. Say both fragments are displayed at the same time in the activity. In this case you can get a reference to another fragment with `FragmentManager`:

```
((MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(...)).addButton(myArgs)
```

If they are placed in different activities or if one replaces another, you need to use arguments `Bundle` to pass the information between the two:

```
SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle;
args.putString("name", "batman");
secondFragment.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, secondFragment).commit();

// later in SecondFragment#onViewCreated
button.setText(getArgments.getString("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Communication between fragments are possible via "interface". You pass on the data thru the activity that links the fragments. After receiving the corresponding data, Fragment B can perform certain actions and refresh the fragment to show the results.

Refer the below link for more info on the execution- 
[passing data between fragments](https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments)