# Fragment Interface Null Pointer Exception in Kotlin with Parent and Child Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Having issues working with a few fragments.

Writing all this kotlin.

I have a MainActivity (Single Activity App). I'm trying to get the parent fragment to communicate a string to the child fragments. When following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) it just loops continuously. Any other solution I've come across just results in a null pointer exception.

[Basic communication between two fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700798/basic-communication-between-two-fragments)

I'm using android components navigation also, btw.

In addition I have to then while using that string send list of objects back to the parent fragment from the child fragments.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

clarification, I am running a fragment in bottom nav enviornment that is the parent frag. Then, inside that parent frag is a view pager with a tablayout to switch between fragments. Within those fragments I am trying to add data to a list using a fab button and an alert dialog. Everything works in the individual fragments it's the data sharing is what I'm struggling with. I have not tried the bundle yet as I wasn't sure it would work. I'll give it a try though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using bundle?

```
var bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle)
```

you can get the data in the destination fragment like so

```
arguments?.getString("amount")
```

this is for sending data from parent to child, as for sending it backward I'm not sure if you can actually do that, as far as I know when you press back you just destroy the current fragment and bring up the previous fragment to screen, you aren't creating or calling it again so I don't think you can send any data without actually recreating the parent fragment.

Comment: updated my question for clarification. I haven't tried the bundle will give that a go. The concept was a bit confusing.

Comment: for most situations, bundles are used to share data between two fragments or activities too, did you give it a try? did it work?

Comment: The problem is I'm navigating to a new fragment. It's a viewpager (two fragments) that is needs to update the list in the parent fragment that the viewpager is inside.